# Show that $\int_0^\infty \left|\frac{\cos x}{1+x}\right| \ dx$ diverges

Tags: calculus, integration

> Show that $$\int_0^\infty \left|\frac{\cos x}{1+x}\right| \ dx$$ diverges

My Try:
$$\int_0^\infty \left|\frac{\cos x}{1+x}\right| \ dx \ge \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{\pi n-\pi/2}^{\pi n + \pi/2} \left|\frac{\cos x}{1+x}\right| \ dx \ge 2\sum_{n=0} \int_{\pi n}^{\pi n + \pi /2} \frac{\cos x}{x+1} \ dx$$

At this phase I thought about replacing the $\cos(x)$ with a linear function, and create an easy to calculate area (A triangle) but it seems like over-complicating after all. What should I do instead?

Comment: One approach would be to ignore regions where $|\cos x| < \frac{1}{2}$, bound the other regions below by $\frac{1}{2}$, and sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\int_{n\pi-\frac\pi2}^{n\pi+\frac\pi2}\left|\frac{\cos x}{x+1}\right|\,dx
  \ge\int_{n\pi-\frac\pi2}^{n\pi+\frac\pi2}
    \frac{|\cos x|}{n\pi+\frac\pi2+1}\,dx
  =\frac2{n\pi+\frac\pi2+1}\ ,$$
and the sum of these diverges.

Comment: Nice! thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^\infty \frac{|\cos(x)|}{1+x} dx \gt \sum_{n \ge 0} \int_{2n\pi}^{2n\pi+\pi/4} \frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}dx \gt \sum_{n \ge 0} \int_{2n\pi}^{2n\pi+\pi/4} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2(1+x)}dx \gt \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2(1+2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4})} = +\infty.$